# Mage::log doesn't print in system.log in Magento

Tags: magento

my Mage::log() are never displayed in system.log

- I did SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true" in htaccess and check it's ok in Magento/index.php
- I enabled to yes the dev log settings and check in database it's well done
- my magento/var/log folder and system.log are set to 777

Did I forget something ?

Magento ver. 1.12.0.2

Comment: Did u give 777 permission to magento/var folder

Answer (score 11):

Check in your webserver's temp directory. If the application cannot write to *./var/log/*, this is where it ends up.

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed a chmod story
I did one little (magento/) chmod -R 777 var/  and all was fixed

Comment: Next issue is How to post easily in stackoverflow :-(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that system.log is chown'ed to the webserver user. Mine is www-data. It also is chmod 777.  I've noticed that when your /magentoroot/var/log files do not exist or are not set up correctly, magento will write log files / cache files to /tmp.

Also, do not delete logfiles. Use sudo truncate -s0 logfilename.log

It clears them.

Comment: "do not delete logfiles" Why?